# how to run GDM on raspberry pi 2

Tags: linux, archlinux, xorg

I need to run GDM on raspberry pi 2 with a fresh arch linux. I installed:

```
xf86-video-fbdev
xorg-xinit
gdm
```

I created a `~/.xinitrc` containing:

```
exec gdm
```

But when I use `startx` I get some text then a black screen.

Comment: You need to explain in detail what you have already tried.

Comment: i tried install xf86-video-fbdev drivers installing xorg and xorg-xinit and installing gdm then i created file in ~/.xinitrc and type in exec gdm save it but then i type startx and it shows some text and then screen goes black

Comment: `gdm` (gnome display manager) is an alternative to `lightdm`, `xdm` or `kdm` (the first is the default for a Raspbian install IIRC).  That being the case I'd expect some part of the package handling system to have at least woken up at one point to ask "Do you want to use gdm or <insert current display manager utility here>, dear superuser?"

Answer (score 2):

GDM is a [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)).  As described in that wikipedia article:

> In the X Window System, an X display manager is **a graphical login manager** which starts a session on an X server from the same or another computer.
>
> **A display manager presents the user with a login screen.** A session starts when a user successfully enters a valid combination of username and password.

Genrally what happens after you log in is the DM then runs your `.xinitrc` script.

But this is not how you are using it.  You are logging in on the console, then trying to start X and run GDM as if it were a [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment), which is a very different thing.

If you wish to use GDM as a display manager (i.e., a graphical login), you will have to enable that through systemd, probably:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Should work, although I am not an arch user and do not know any potential caveats about their configuration.

However, you will still need something *other than* a display manager listed in your xinitrc.

Comment: no its not working i tried systemctl start gdm.service but what happen is black screen and nothing else

Comment: ok i installed xfce4 and some more packages: "pacman -S xorg-utils xorg-xinit dbus xorg-server  xorg-utils xorg-server-utils mesa xorg-twm xterm xorg-xclock" and edit /.xinitrc: exec startxfce4 but now its gives me error:"/usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg: error while loading shared libraries:/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: invalid ELF header

Comment: You've broken something and/or installed something from an invalid repository.  It sounds as if you are new to both the pi and linux -- I recommend you create a new image using Raspbian, which should make things a easier.

Comment: i tried raspbian too before arch and i dont like it i tried install gdm on raspbian and its runs :) but when i select gnome its shows black screen with cursor

Comment: im going to reinstall arch install the packages and see what happens but when its will not run i will install raspbian as the last change

Answer (score 0):

According to the ArchWiki [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc) on xinitrc you should have copied the working default in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` to your `~/.xinitrc` and modified that to meet your requirements because the former has some stuff that you need, specifically:

```
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?* ; do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi
```

Further reading of that specific article does look to be very helpful in this area.

Comment: Ok i will try it

Answer (score -1):

I did it: I installed some packages from xorg and now when I type startx it starts xterm, and in xterm I type

```
systemctl start gdm.service
```

Get black screen, but after 1 minute it shows a screen with gdm finally.